# Scala:if condition returning Unit as type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a below code

```
val calDF = if (path1.size > 0 && path2.size > 0) {
  func1(df1).union(func2(df2))
  println("Processed 1")
} else if (path1.size > 0) {
  func1(df1)
  println("Processed 2")
} else if (path2.size > 0) {
  func2(df2)
  println("Processed 3")
}
```

When I am running the code I am getting below output when I should be getting it as dataframe type.

```
calDF: Unit = ()
```

If I just run func2(df2) I am getting correct data. What am I missing here?

Comment: What should happen if neither condition was true? - Also, you are basically printing in each `if` what other return type did you even expected?

Comment: Look at the last line of each `if statement`. that's what your code returns as result

Comment: thanks..i used the println before calling the function!

Answer (score 3):

The last line of every code block produces the returned value of that block. `println` returns `Unit`.

Reorder the lines of each block:

```scala
val calDF = if (path1.size > 0 && path2.size > 0) {
  println("Processed 1")
  func1(df1).union(func2(df2))
} else if (path1.size > 0) {
  println("Processed 2")
  func1(df1)
} else if (path2.size > 0) {
  println("Processed 3")
  func2(df2)
} else {
  // something that computes a value
}
```

Also, if there is no else clause then Unit is returned.

Comment: _" println returns null."_ `println` returns **Unit** and since that `if` doesn't have a final `else` the whole return type will be **Any**.

Comment: yes I removed the last else if condition and used just else!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are right, I am rusty

Comment: @justanothertekguy  That changes the logic but you know the requirements so if you say so, I am good